# How to get user id of the sender who sent the message in a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api, pyrogram

My telegram bot is an admin in a channel.

I'm listening to message using on_message handler.

I want to get the username/userid of the user of that message. How can I do that in pyrogram or another python telegram bot library?

Answer (score 2):

Telegram doesn't expose the username or their ID for messages in a channel. Not even to other admins.

The only indication you get is `Message.author_signature` as a string, which contains the "Signature of the post author for messages in channels, or the custom title of an anonymous group administrator."

See https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Message

Answer (score 1):

Using the `update.message.from_user` from [this python library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) , you can get pretty much all the user info